# hall current sensor potential failure mode

Tags: current, sensor, ac

I was curious what are potential common failure modes for hall-based ac current sensors in a mains ac environment? Specifically those like the acs712 and [acs723](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS723-Datasheet.ashx). Assume you have a 5amp current sensor, and draw 20+ amps of current through it for a sustained period of time. What would happen?

Comment: You have to go above 65A to get out of spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify AC mains operation and a 5A sensor.
This answer focuses mainly (but not solely) on the consequences of the internal shunt in the sensor IC failing open circuit (as can happen).

My discussion below assumes potential fault currents far in excess of 5A, or indeed, in excess of the continuous 65A rated current of the ACS723. I've also mentioned DC sensing operation. AC sensing is somewhat less design demanding than DC due to the greater likelihood that an arc will extinguish.

In many mains based applications limiting currents to below eg 65A under short circuit is 'easy enough'. However, if current limiting is not specifically designed in, AC mains will often happily source many many hundreds of amps under short circuit. The duration of such overcurrent events may be short - but not always short enough.

I'll deal only with the ACS723 as the 712 has an inferior specification and is obsolete. Anything that applies to the 723 will apply to the 712, but more so.

**_____________________________________**

The ACS723 is rated at 65A continuous and claims 0.65 milliohm shunt resistance.
At 65A dissipation = I^2.R = 2.75 Watt.

Thermal resistance is 5 C/W when mounted in their development board or 23 C/W junction to air bare.  At say 3 Watt dissipation (add solder joints,...) temperature rise above ambient would be about 15 degrees c and 115 c respectively. Tjmax is specified at 165 c. That allows (just) operation in 50 c free air with no heatsinking - so quite modest heatsinking will usually keep it "cool enough". Cooler is better for long life but under those conditions no major short term failures should be expected.

If you use it in a system with a battery capable of providing hundreds of amps (as I have done) or with AC mains and a good current path, and then experience a short circuit somewhere "downstream" of the sensor (as I have done) then things rapidly can get 'not so good'.

At say 200A the dissipation rises to 26 Watts - the evaluation board heatsinking will keep the temperature in check for a very short while - but 26W is too much for any normal PCB copper based heatsinking. At 300A, it's toast.

At somewhere above 65A and quite possibly well below 200A the internal shunt may fuse. Unless they have designed an HRC fuse into the package (and they haven't) then under DC an impressive arc **will** form and sustain until interrupted elsewhere. With AC it MAY not form a sustaining arc, but probably will.

Once an arc forms, all bets are off.
Ask me how I know :-).

The package will carbonise, the PCBA (unless super super special) will join in the fun and a small fire will probably start.  Worst case, and quite probably, energy from the current monitored circuit will enter the now-no-way-isolated low voltage power supply and control circuits. Results will depend on design, protection against such an event and Murphy.

To prevent the above you can

- limit Imax to 65A in some way
- fuse the circuit to open the fuse below 65A.
  A fast blow fuse is required as you don't know how fast the IC shunt fuses, and you MUST prevent it doing so.
- Prevent more than 65A flowing in the shunt in some manner during higher current faults. This is a less likely approach but could be achieved with eg a fast acting electronic bypass.

Placing the low voltage side of the sensor in an isolated node with 'communications' and powering via fail-safe interfaces is certainly possible and may be viable. But

- In situations where high fault currents cannot be designed out I'd expect high current side HRC fusing to be a reasonably good solution.
- In situations where 5A max load was desired and significant power loss in feed circuits was acceptable then ensuring adequate resistance (or inductance with AC) is present is probably satisfactory.  eg at 230 VAC, to limit I to 65A max R = V/I = 300Vpk/65 ~~~= 5 ohms. At 5A the loss in 5 ohms is P = I^2R =  125 Watts! This is a significant dissipation level -  an HRC fuse and more modest resistance levels are probably in order.

**_______________________**

**HRC Fuses!:**

I mentioned HRC (High Rupture Capacity) fuses several times above.
The need for such fuses when arcs can form is crucial. A fuse which opens at say 20A but which can sustain an arc of hundreds of amps (which many non HRC fuses can) is worse than useless as it provides a degree of confidence which is wholly without foundation.

Comment: would something like a polyfuse be worthwhile for ac mains applications instead of a non-reset-able fuse? i know that most household circuits are either 15 or 20 amps (atleast here in the US), but the surge currents can get quite high before the breaker trips, but I don't foresee cases of greater than 65A? The 200A+ was just an example I hope ;) Appreciate your insight.

Comment: @Alex MAins impedance for residential premises can (and should) be well under 1 Ohm. In order that a load such as eg an oven does not reduced Vmains significantly and lose excessive energy in the wiring the unfused potential fault current needs to be able to be significantly greater than the maximum rated load. If your premises has a max rated load of say 60A you can assume that fault current can be many hundreds of amps. 200A is certainly not 'just an example', sadly. Fuse ratings will be much lower - but, is your fuse or shunt "faster" and will a failed shunt sustain an arc? ...

Comment: A main fuse or breaker is designed not too. A charred PCB and IC package not so well. || Easy test: Provide a realistic minimum length circuit from near switchboard. Short with hall sensor shunt. What happens. (I don't know. I do know what happened to me with a 24 V, 40Ah LiFePO4 battery :-) ). || Polyfuses are necessarily slow acting. Data sheets will tell you how slow, but as they are heating a polymer medium with some mass I'd expect a sensor-shunt to fail far faster than they heat. | Apart from cost and PCB area a fuse is not a major issue as a short needs operator action.

Comment: i wish allegro had a more in-depth example circuit or eval board. most shields i've seen don't even have sufficient heat-sinking. also wouldn't a fast-acting fuse cause potential issues if the load draws a lot of current on start up?

Comment: @Alex Life is complex :-). I'd expect that most applications would never see the melt down failure that I described. That's a fairly worst case even that you need to be aware of but hope to never see. A fuse that will prevent that failure can probably be rated at 30 to 50 A. As long as it's faster than the shunt (which has far more thermal inertia than a fuse wire plus some PCB heat sinking) then it will probably protect the shunt AND never be needed. Just thinning the PCB tracks at some point so they become the failure point may be enough.  | "Why is there a solder pad with no hole at ...

Comment: ... either end of this thin track section?" -> Oh, that's for soldering in the new repair 30A "fuse" wire when needed. :-)